# set of almost complex structures on $\mathbb R^4$ as two disjoint spheres

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry

The set of almost complex structures on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is given by
$$ M_n = \frac{GL(2n,\mathbb R)}{GL(n,\mathbb C)} = \mathcal C_+ \sqcup \mathcal C_-,$$
taking into account that $\det = \pm 1$ gives two disjoint sets.

How do we show that $M_2=S^2 \sqcup S^2$?
Moreover, I'm a bit confused by dimensions: how does $\dim_{\mathbb R}M_2=8$ relates with the latter decomposition?

This is exercise 1.2.1 from the book *Complex geometry* by Huybrechts.

Comment: I am a beginner and I am confused. Is the decomposition $\mathcal C_+ \sqcup \mathcal C_-$ really because of $\det = \pm 1$? In the case of $\mathbb R^2$, the two complex structures are given by $J_1=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $J_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. But both of these have $\det=1$. What am I missing?

Comment: @MohithNagaraju: Since $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acts transitively, there is $A \in GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ such that $J_2 = A^{-1}J_1A$. If $A$ has positive determinant, then $J_1$ and $J_2$ are in the same connected component, while if $A$ has negative determinant, then $J_1$ and $J_2$ are in different connected components. Note, $A$ is not unique and if $J_2 = B^{-1}J_1B$, then $A = CB$ where $C \in GL(1, \mathbb{C})$ - note that $\det C > 0$, so $\det A$ and $\det B$ have the same sign. In the (left) quotient $GL(2, \mathbb{R})/GL(1, \mathbb{C})$, the equivalence class $[A]$ corresponds to $J_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, $M$ is *not* diffeomorphic to $S^2\coprod S^2$ for dimension reasons.

On the other hand, what is true is $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \coprod S^2$.

(The following argument is partly adapted from a [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1950-001-04/S0002-9939-1950-0037311-6/S0002-9939-1950-0037311-6.pdf) of Montgomery)

To see this, it's enough to show that $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/Gl(2,\mathbb{C})$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$, where $Gl^+$ denotes those matrices of positive determinant.

Now, consider the subgroups $U(2)\subseteq Gl(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $SO(4)\subseteq Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})$.

It's relatively well known that $Gl(2,\mathbb{C})$ is diffeomorphic to $U(2)\times \mathbb{R}^4$ and that $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(4)\times \mathbb{R}^{10}$.  Further, in the usual inclusion $Gl(2,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})$, $U(2)$ becomes a subgroup of $SO(4)$.

Now, the chain of subgroups $U(2)\subseteq SO(4)\subseteq Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})$ gives rise to a homogeneous fibration $$SO(4)/U(2)\rightarrow Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/U(2)\rightarrow Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/SO(4).$$  In light of the above diffeomorphisms, $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/SO(4)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{10}$.  Since Euclidean spaces are contractible, it follows that the fibration is trivial, so $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/U(2)$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(4)/U(2)\times \mathbb{R}^{10}$.  In particular, $SO(4)/U(2)$ is homotopy equivalent to $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/U(2)$.

Now, consider the chain of subgroups $U(2)\subseteq Gl(2,\mathbb{C})\subseteq Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})$.  This gives rise to a homogeneous fibration $$Gl(2,\mathbb{C})/U(2)\rightarrow Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/U(2) \rightarrow Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/Gl(2,\mathbb{C}).$$  In this case, the fiber is diffeomoprhic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, which immediately implies that $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/U(2)$ is homotopy equivalent to $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/Gl(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Putting the last two paragraphs together, we now know that $SO(4)/U(2)$ is homotopy equivalent to $Gl^+(4,\mathbb{R})/Gl(2,\mathbb{C})$.

To finish off the argument, we need to show that $SO(4)/U(2)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2$.
To see this, first note that $U(2)$ intersects the center $Z(SO(4)) = \{\pm I\}$ of $SO(4)$.  It follows that $$SO(4)/U(2) \cong [SO(4)/Z(SO(4)]/[U(2)/(Z(SO(4))\cap U(2))].$$

But $SO(4)/Z(SO(4))\cong SO(3)\times SO(3)$ and $U(2)/(Z(SO(4))\cap U(2)) \cong SO(3)\times S^1$.  So, $SO(4)/U(2)\cong (SO(3)\times SO(3))/(SO(3)\times S^1)\cong SO(3)/S^1$.

But the standard action of $SO(3)$ on $S^2$ is transitive with stabilizer $S^1$, so $SO(3)/S^1 \cong S^2$.

Comment: This argument works for any $n$ to show $Gl^+(2n,\mathbb{R})/Gl(n,\mathbb{C})$ is always homotopy equivalent to $SO(2n)/U(n)$.  I don't think $SO(2n)/U(n)$ has a nicer description for most $n$.  But, when $n=1$, it's trivial.  When $n=2$, it's $S^2$, and when $n=3$, it's $SU(4)/U(3) = \mathbb{C}P^3$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer; I also found an alternative way of looking at this fact, though I'm not able to fully understand it. It goes as follows: a matrix in $GL^+(2n,\mathbb R)/GL(n,\mathbb C)$ has polar decomposition $J=SO=-O^{-1}S^{-1}=(O^tS^{-1}O)(-O^{-1})$. This is OK, and implies that $O=-O^{-1}=P^{-1}J_0P$ defines an element $U(n)P \in SO(2n)/U(n)$: what I don't understand of this last statement is how the properties of $O$ imply that $P \in GL(2n,\mathbb R)$ is also in $SO(2n)$. Then one could conclude observing that $SO(4)/U(2)$ is $S^2$. Could you help?

Comment: Here $J_0$ is the standard symplectic form

Comment: @jj_p:  I'm not sure I understand all the notation.  For example, why is $SO = -O^{-1} S$?  Is $J$ a specific matrix?  And are you claiming that any orthogonal matrix can be obtained from $J_0$ by conjugating?

Comment: I try to explain better: $J$ is a generic complex structure, s.t. $J^2=-1$, and the polar decomposition is given by a symmetric matrix $S=S^t$ times an orthogonal matrix $O^t=O^{-1}$. So the equality you cite, follows from $J=-J^{-1}$. The other property one uses to prove the second set of equalities is uniqueness of $O$ in the polar decomposition. Does these clarify notation?

Comment: @jj_p:  Sorry for the late response.  The farthest I've been able to get is that $(PP^t) J_0 (PP^t)^{-1} = J_0$.  So, we conjugate $J_0$ by a symmetric matrix and get $J_0$ back.  I've been unable to show that this implies $PP^t = I$, and I'd have no idea how to get to showing $\det P = 1$ from there.  Sorry!